# How do you get Eclipse to auto-generate a main method for a new Java class?

Tags: java, eclipse

Does anyone know a reason why my Eclipse does not preload

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

when I create a new class? What can I do to make it appear automatically?

Comment: Because in general, you'll only want one class with a `main` method...

Comment: What would it even mean if every class had a `Main`? Which one would run when the program starts?

Comment: @Raymond The one you told it to.

Comment: Oli & Raymond - really? Any class can have a main, and there are plenty of times where all classes can have a main.

Comment: Most classes in most programs don't have or need a `main` method. Instead of having Eclipse add it automatically, you can just type main(Ctrl+Space), and it'll autocomplete the whole signature for you.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But what would be the point of having N `Main` methods when only one of them will be used? That would just create two new categories of problems. (1) "Why am I getting the error "more than one entry point defined?" (2) "Why isn't my Main getting called?"

Comment: @raymond I'm not saying it's right, but you might have a project for spawning classes with `main` methods. `MainMethodFactory`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis While there may be unusual cases where multiple `Main` methods may make sense, it is a bad choice of default.

Comment: @RaymondChen I agree with you.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Yes, all classes *can* have a `main`.  I'm saying that most of the time, that's not something you want.  It would be annoying if Eclipse always created a `main` method for new classes.

Comment: @RaymondChen: You shouldn't get problem #1 in Java.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Sorry. When the question was first posted, it was not tagged `java` so I assumed `C#`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> *"what can i do to make it appear automatically? "*

- Go to create New Java Class dialog
- See a part that says "Which method stubs would you like to create?"
- check `public static void main(String[] args)`

[image]

Answer (score 28):

Type `main` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>. The eclipse content assist will pop up with main method. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best practise is to use only keyboard. It makes workflow a lot faster.

1. Create new java class with `Ctrl+n`
2. on dialog box, enter its (class) name
3. use `(left)Alt+v` to easily tick checkbox for - `public static void main(String[] args)`
4. then press `[enter]` Finish and voila class is ready...