# Eclipse: How to make public static void main(String[] args) default when creating new class

Tags: eclipse

On Eclipse: I remember, before, the checkbox for public static void main(String[] args) was checked as default when creating a new class file. I turned if off at some point and now I can't find where to turn it back on. please help

I'm not looking for a shortcut key to add this. I want to make this setting the default setting

[image: photo here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get Eclipse to auto-generate a main method for a new Java class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726033/how-do-you-get-eclipse-to-auto-generate-a-main-method-for-a-new-java-class)

Comment: Actually, I'm not looking for a shortcut key, I'm trying to make that as a default setting

Comment: I'm frankly not sure it's configurable.  Either fron anywhere in Eclipse > Window > Preferences, or by editing one or another properties files in Eclipse.  Q: Are you *sure* you've ever actually seen it default to "checked"?   SUGGESTION: Check out this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWizards/article.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code templates` and in the `Configure generated code and comments` section choose `Code -> Class body`.

Press Edit and write the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] argrs)
{

}
```

Then press OK and apply the changes

[image]

Now every time that you create a new Java class the main method appears as default.